# How to find elements that are common to all lists in a nested list?

Tags: python, overlap, nested-lists

I have a large nested list and each list within the nested list contains a list of numbers that are formatted as floats. However every individual list in the nested list  is the same except for a few exceptions. I want to extract the numbers that are common to all of the lists in the nested list. A simple example of my problem is shown below:

```
nested_list = [[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0,13.0,14.0,15.0],
              [2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0,13.0,14.0],
              [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0,13.0,14.0],
              [2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0,13.0,14.0,15.0]]
```

In the following case I would want to extract the following:

```
common_vals = [2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0,13.0,14.0]
```

I tried to use set intersections to solve this but since I wasn't able to get this to work on all of the elements of the nested list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `reduce` and `set.intersection`:

```
>>> reduce(set.intersection, map(set, nested_list))
set([2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0])
```

Use `itertools.imap` for memory efficient solution.

## Timing Comparisons:

```
>>> lis = [[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0,13.0,14.0,15.0],
              [2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0,13.0,14.0],
              [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0,13.0,14.0],
              [2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0,13.0,14.0,15.0]]
>>> %timeit set.intersection(*map(set, lis))
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.5 us per loop
>>> %timeit set.intersection(*(set(e) for e in lis))
10000 loops, best of 3: 14.4 us per loop
>>> %timeit reduce(set.intersection, map(set, lis))
10000 loops, best of 3: 12.8 us per loop
>>> %timeit reduce(set.intersection, imap(set, lis))
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.1 us per loop
>>> %timeit set.intersection(set(lis[0]), *islice(lis, 1, None))
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.6 us per loop


>>> lis = [[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0,13.0,14.0,15.0],
              [2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0,13.0,14.0],
              [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0,13.0,14.0],
              [2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0,13.0,14.0,15.0]]*1000
>>> %timeit set.intersection(*map(set, lis))
10 loops, best of 3: 16.4 ms per loop
>>> %timeit set.intersection(*(set(e) for e in lis))
10 loops, best of 3: 15.8 ms per loop
>>> %timeit reduce(set.intersection, map(set, lis))
100 loops, best of 3: 16.3 ms per loop
>>> %timeit reduce(set.intersection, imap(set, lis))
10 loops, best of 3: 13.8 ms per loop
>>> %timeit set.intersection(set(lis[0]), *islice(lis, 1, None))
100 loops, best of 3: 8.4 ms per loop


>>> lis = [[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0,13.0,14.0,15.0],              [2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0,13.0,14.0],
              [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0,13.0,14.0],
              [2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0,13.0,14.0,15.0]]*10**5
>>> %timeit set.intersection(*map(set, lis))  
1 loops, best of 3: 1.92 s per loop
>>> %timeit set.intersection(*(set(e) for e in lis))
1 loops, best of 3: 2.17 s per loop
>>> %timeit reduce(set.intersection, map(set, lis))
1 loops, best of 3: 2.14 s per loop
>>> %timeit reduce(set.intersection, imap(set, lis))
1 loops, best of 3: 1.52 s per loop
>>> %timeit set.intersection(set(lis[0]), *islice(lis, 1, None))
1 loops, best of 3: 913 ms per loop
```

**Conclusion:**

Steven Rumbalski's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17351027/846892) is clearly the best one in terms of efficiency.

Answer (score 6):

Try this, it's the simplest solution:

```
set.intersection(*map(set, nested_list))
```

Or if you prefer to use generator expressions, which should be a more efficient solution in terms of memory usage:

```
set.intersection(*(set(e) for e in nested_list))
```

Comment: In this particular case, the generator expression is turned into a tuple before calling the function, so there is no benefit.

Answer (score 6):

Ashwini Chaudhary's solution is elegant, but could be quite inefficient for large inputs because it creates many intermediate sets.  If your `nested_list` is large do this:

```
>>> set.intersection(set(nested_list[0]), *itertools.islice(nested_list, 1, None))
set([2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0])
```

Comment: Note that `nested_list[1:]` creates a shallow copy of `nested_list`, which could be avoided using `itertools.islice(nested_list, 1, None)`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach:  Good point.  Changed to use `itertools.islice`.  Sven Marnach is back!

Answer (score 0):

Count occurences of each element in sets of lists occuring in nested_list, if occurence equals number of lements in nested_list, it is common to all.
You do not need the set conversion if elements of nested_list do not have numbers repeated in them

```
nested_list = [[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0,13.0,14.0,15.0],
              [2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0,13.0,14.0],
              [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0,13.0,14.0],
              [2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0,13.0,14.0,15.0]]

from collections import Counter
result = [val for val,cnt in Counter([x for t in nested_list for x in set(t)]).items() if cnt == len(nested_list)]
print result


 #  [2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0]
```