# get intersection of list of sets

Tags: python, list, set

I want python to get the intersection of a list of sets.

For example, I have a function that returns `s` a list of sets following:

```
[set(0,1,3), set(1,3)]
```

As you can see the intersection of this is the set {1,3}. How can I get python to obtain the intersection? What I've been doing so far is iterating over the list. But I can't seen to get the intersection.

Solution should be able to deal with an n element list of sets not just a pair.

Any ideas?

Comprehensions are welcome

As an aside why is the set rendered as `set([])` in other words why not just with curly braces?

Comment: That is not the *union*, that is the *intersection* of the sets. The union would be `{0, 1, 3}`.

Comment: The curly brace syntax was added to the language later.

Comment: @MartijnPieters what an embarrassing brain fart. thanks

Comment: `{}` is an empty dictionary literal, not an empty set literal.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use `set.intersection`:

```
>>> lis = [set((0,1,3)), set((1,3))]
>>> set.intersection(*lis)
set([1, 3])
```

For union use `set.union`:

```
>>> set.union(*lis)
set([0, 1, 3])
```

If [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17350800/846892) matters then use this:

```
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> set.intersection(set(lis[0]), *islice(lis, 1, None))
set([1, 3])
```

Comment: Deleted my answer since you added the `set.union` one to yours. Nice one. :)

Comment: any documentation on what the wildcard does?

Comment: @franklin http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments

Comment: If your list is empty this will generate an error.
Suggestion:
    "set.intersection(*lis) if lis else set()"
or:
    "set.union(*lis) if lis else set()"

Comment: what does the * do before it?

Comment: @O.rka `*` in function call means unpack the arguments of the iterable and pass them to the function as individual arguments, so `set.intersection(*lis)` is equivalent to `set.intersection(set((0,1,3)), set((1,3)))`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
reduce(set.intersection, L)

In [83]: L = [set([0,1,3]), set([1,3])]

In [84]: reduce(set.intersection, L)
Out[84]: set([1, 3])
```

Comment: This also fails when `L` has zero elements